# Create new column in a dataframe based on group by and other conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have a data frame where you can have either one row or two rows by id.

I need to create two new columns where for each id group if we have one row only. We determine the values based on the condition on one column 'type'. If there are two rows, the values of the new columns depend on the conditions on 'type' and get values from the other row of the group.

An example will speak better.

We have at first this data frame:

| index | id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | d |
| 1 | 2 | pu |
| 2 | 3 | pu |
| 3 | 3 | d |
| 4 | 4 | pu |
| 5 | 4 | d |

We expect that output:

```
if 1 row per 'id':
   if type == 'd':
      didx = -1
      puidx = -10
   elif type == 'pu':
      didx = -10
      puidx = -1
elif 2 rows per 'id':
   if type == 'd':
      didx = -1
      puidx = index of the other row with same 'id'
   elif type == 'pu':
      didx = index of the other row with same 'id'
      puidx = -1
```

| index | id | type | didx | puidx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | d | -1 | -10 |
| 1 | 2 | pu | -10 | -1 |
| 2 | 3 | pu | 3 | -1 |
| 3 | 3 | d | -1 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | pu | 5 | -1 |
| 5 | 4 | d | -1 | 4 |

I assume that we need to use groupby and apply. But not sure how to make it efficient.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to create a `df` with `first` and `last` indices for all groups in column `id` (here assigned to `g`).
- Now, for both `didx` and `puidx`, we use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to assign either `-1` or `-10`.
- Next, we chain [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) combined with [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). For, `didx` we check `~df.id.duplicated(keep='last')`, and if `True` we want the last index for the "group" (so: `g['last']` mapped to `df.id`), else we keep the value from `didx`. For `puidx`, we change `last` to `first` both times.

```
g = df.groupby('id')['index'].agg(['first','last'])

df['didx'] = df.type.map({'d':-1,'pu':-10}).where(
    ~df.id.duplicated(keep='last'),
    df.id.map(g['last']))

df['puidx'] = df.type.map({'d':-10,'pu':-1}).where(
    ~df.id.duplicated(keep='first'),
    df.id.map(g['first']))

print(df)

       id type  didx  puidx
index                      
0       1    d    -1    -10
1       2   pu   -10     -1
2       3   pu     3     -1
3       3    d    -1      2
4       4   pu     5     -1
5       4    d    -1      4
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. What I was looking for and better than adding columns for intermediary results.